# Why is jQuery animate setting my div to display: none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

jQuery Animate does unintended things to my CSS. When animating `paddingLeft`, it sets div to `display: none`; that's unintended and I can't figure out why it does that. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsw2hqyw/4/)

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#sidebar-wrapper').width() == 0){
            $("#sidebar-wrapper").animate({
                width: 'toggle'
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
            });$("#page-content-wrapper").animate({
                paddingLeft: 'toggle'
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
            });
        }else{
            $("#sidebar-wrapper").animate({
                width: 'toggle'
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
            });$("#page-content-wrapper").animate({
                paddingLeft: 'toggle'
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**SOLVED:**
Here's a Solve if anyone is interested: [FixedFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rb0y6g0/1/)

Comment: can you include the minimal html too?

Comment: I'd like to see a plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: May be due to this: ` width: 'toggle'`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hsw2hqyw/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs:

> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings 'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding and showing animations that take into account the display type of the element. In order to use jQuery's built-in toggle state tracking, the 'toggle' keyword must be consistently given as the value of the property being animated.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

If my memory serves, and as the docs indicate, these shortcuts do extra work to literally "show" and "hide" the element on animation start and complete. It would seem jquery takes into account the initial display and then stores that to restore it later. Toggle is just a macro of "show" and "hide" and seems to function in the same way.

Comment: well then. how can i resolve this? just use += and -= ?

Comment: That seems like a separate question than the one posted here, but I did whip this up for you really quick: https://jsfiddle.net/aubricus/6rb0y6g0/

Comment: Alternatively, you could use JS to simply toggle a CSS class or classes and let CSS handle the animations.

Comment: I actually fixed it myself after hearing what toggle does. https://jsfiddle.net/6rb0y6g0/1/

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped! :)